# How to read Hadoop sequence file using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, sequencefile

I have a sequence file generated by Spark using saveAsObjectFile function. File content is just some int numbers. And I want to read it locally with Java. Here is my code:

```
    FileSystem fileSystem = null;
    SequenceFile.Reader in = null;
    try {
        fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path path = new Path("D:\\spark_sequence_file");
        in = new SequenceFile.Reader(conf, SequenceFile.Reader.file(path));
        Writable key = (Writable)
                ReflectionUtils.newInstance(in.getKeyClass(), conf);
        BytesWritable value = new BytesWritable();
        while (in.next(key, value)) {
            byte[] val_byte = value.getBytes();
            int val = ByteBuffer.wrap(val_byte, 0, 4).getInt();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I can't read it correctly; I just get all the same values, and obviously they are wrong.  Here is my answer snapshot

[image]

The file head is like this:
[image]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't read it correctly"? Is the shown header wrong, or right, or why is it shown?

Comment: If they are ints, maybe using an IntWritable could help, instead of ByteWritable?

Comment: @kutschkem, I mean I just got the same numbers, and they are wrong. I have updated my question. And IntWritable is wrong, the file is generated by spark, and spark use byteswritable.

Comment: Ok the question makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't use saveAsObjectFile function, I am still testing. If I get the answer, I will tell you.@kutschkem

Answer (score 1):

In Hadoop usually the Keys are of type WritableComparable and values are of type Writable. Keeping this basic concept in mind I read the Sequence File in the below way.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
Path path = new Path(PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE);
SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(FileSystem.get(config), path, config);
WritableComparable key = (WritableComparable) reader.getKeyClass().newInstance();
Writable value = (Writable) reader.getValueClass().newInstance();
while (reader.next(key, value))
  // do some thing
reader.close();
```

The data issue in your case might be because of the reason you are using `saveAsObjectFile()` rather than using `saveAsSequenceFile(String path,scala.Option<Class<? extends org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec>> codec)`

Please try to use the above method and see if the issue persist.